# Use Clairaut's Theorem to find an effecient way to solve $f_{yyzzx}$.

Tags: calculus, functions

I just asked a similar question, but is there any other way the $f_{yyzzx}$ could be rearranged to get a number other than $0$ in the end? 
When $x^2\sin(4y)+z^3(6x-y)+y^4$.

I have $f_y=4x^2\cos(4y)-z^3+4y^3$, then $f_{yy}=-16x^2\sin(4y)+12y^2$

Comment: Title: "solve"?  Solve is a thing done to (systems of) equations.  You *evaluate* derivatives and other expressions.

Comment: "I just asked a similar question..."  Where?  [citation needed].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z,w) = x^2 \sin(4y) + z^3(6x-y)+y^4$.  Since $x$, $y$, $z$, and $w$ are continuous functions and sums, differences, products, cosines, and sines of continuous functions are continuous, $f$ is continuous and all of its (multiple) derivatives are continuous.  Clairaut's theorem therefore allows us to reorder the specified partial derivatives freely without changing the value of the result.

Only the middle term contains a "$z$", so $f_z$ contains only one term, $3z^2(6x-y)$.  Differentiating that by $x$ or $y$ leaves a constant times $z^2$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} 3z^2(6x-y) &= 18z^2  \text{ and }  \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} 3z^2(6x-y) &= -3z^2  \text{.}
\end{align*}
From either of these, partially differentiating with respect to $y$ again leaves $0$.

So, either $f_{zxy} = 0$ or $f_{zyy} = 0$, further partial differentiation remains zero, and Clauraut's theorem tells us the reordered derivatives have the same value, so the requested partial derivative of $f$ is zero.

---

A different way of thinking about it.  With $f$ given and after observing that we may reorder the derivatives as we like, we examine tha terms of $f$.  The first term has no $z$ in it and neither does the third.  If $z$ appears in the list of variables with respect to which we will differentiate, these terms will vanish before we finish.  "$z$" does appear on the list, so these terms do not contribute to the result.  The middle term is linear in $x$ and $y$, so if $x$ appears twice or $y$ appears twice in the list of variables with respect to which we will differentiate, that term will vanish before we finish. "$y$" does appear twice on the list, so this term also does not contribute to the result.  In this way, we have shown that every term is sent to zero before we finish taking the specified partial derivative.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem simply tells you that the *order* of taking the partial derivatives does not matter in this case.

Recall that taking partial derivatives is a linear operation. For example:
$$
(u+v)_z=u_z+v_z\;.
$$

Because you are taking the derivative wrt $z$ twice, so the first and the third term in $f$ will go away. So you only need to consider the term
$$
z^3(6x-y)=6z^3x-z^3y\;.
$$

But you are differentiating $y$ twice, so you only need to consider $6z^3x$. Now, your turn.

---

In short, write
$$
f = u+v+w,\quad f_{yyzzx} = (u_{zz})_{yyx}+(v)_{yyzzx}+(w_{zz})_{yyx}
$$
and note that
$$
u_{zz}=w_{zz}=0
$$